# How to stop fullcalendar from rendering a full day in week view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

First off I am reading the documentation and I have used minTime and MaxTime to render specific slots.

The problem I have is that the entire day get's rendered and I assume that this can be overridden but I have not been able to find the option that does this if it exists?

I want to render a fullcalendar between 09:00 and 19:00. My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        minTime: '09:00:00',
        maxTime: '19:00:00',
        allDaySlot: false
})
```

My problem:
[image: Image of problem]

Comment: This may require a CSS solutions. Do you have any HTML or CSS to work with?

Comment: After reading your comment i immediately tried setting "overflow:hidden" on the container and it solved the problem. I was so fixed on fullcalendar that i never even considered this, thank you @Adjit. ALTHOUGH is there an option for this in the fullcalendar.js?

Edit: Could you please present this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with CSS and setting the `overflow` property of the calendar.

However, you should also read the documentation on fullcalendar's `height` property.

Quoting the documentation:

> By default, [the height] option is unset and the calendar's height is calculated by aspectRatio.

*You also have the ability to change aspectRatio to whatever you would like. You can read up on that here: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/aspectRatio/*

Height has the input options of:

```
Integer, "auto"
```

With proper usage as:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 650 //[integer, "auto"]
});
```

The documentation for height can be found here: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/